# start again CountDownTimer - android

Tags: android, timer

I read there is no direct way to start again (or update) the time. I try to do :

```
Const.counter = new CustomTimerTask(Const.currentLevel.timeGoal * 1000,1000, importantMessage, showTimerMessage);
                Const.counter.start();
```

every time I want the timer to start again but it isn't working (The old timer remain). What can I do?

EDIT:
I also try this

```
if(Const.counter != null){
                    Const.counter.cancel();
                    Const.counter.start();
                }
                else{
                    Const.counter = new CustomTimerTask(Const.currentLevel.timeGoal * 1000,1000, importantMessage, showTimerMessage);
                    Const.counter.start();
                }
```

but it is suspend and resume and not start again

EDIT 2 : Maybe I will write more of my code:

```
package com.example.fishe;

import android.os.CountDownTimer;
//countdowntimer is an abstract class, so extend it and fill in methods

public class CustomTimerTask extends CountDownTimer{

    private Messages gameoverMes;
    private Messages showRemailTimeMes;

    public CustomTimerTask(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval , Messages gameoverMes , Messages showRemailTimeMes) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        this.gameoverMes = gameoverMes;
        this.showRemailTimeMes =showRemailTimeMes;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        gameoverMes.setMessage("GAME OVER");
        showRemailTimeMes.setMessage(" " + 0);
        Game.gameOver();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        Const.secUntilFinished = millisUntilFinished/1000;
        if( Const.secUntilFinished == 6)
            GameSounds.play(Const.TIME_GOING_TO_OVER,false);
        showRemailTimeMes.setMessage(" " + Const.secUntilFinished);
    }
}
```

I always see "0" in showRemailTimeMes after the first counter I defindes has finished,
although I started the count again.

```
@Override
    public void onResume()
    {

        super.onResume();



        if(Const.counter != null){
            Const.counter = null;
        }
        Const.counter = new CustomTimerTask(Const.currentLevel.timeGoal * 1000,1000,
                importantMessage, showTimerMessage);
        Const.counter.start();
}
```

Comment: Um, well the reason you see "0" is probably because you hardcoded it to `setMessage(" " + 0)`

Comment: But on the function onTick I write:  showRemailTimeMes.setMessage(" " + Const.secUntilFinished); but it still remain 0 !

Comment: try printing out `millisUntilFinished` and see what you get there

Comment: I checked - it is always print the first counter...It is so wired...

Comment: I assume I have other problem so I will continue alone and return if can't solve it

Comment: I don't find any problem in my code.. someone has more suggestion?

Comment: now it show me both the old and the new timer...

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is just destroy the previous instance of CountDownTimer and re-initialize the new instance like,

```
if(Const.counter != null){
     Const.counter = null;
  }
 Const.counter = new CustomTimerTask(Const.currentLevel.timeGoal * 1000,1000,
                                             importantMessage, showTimerMessage);
 Const.counter.start();
```

Comment: You don't understand me. I wan to start again - not stop and resume

Comment: In that case try to create a new instance and start it!

Comment: you are checking `if(Const.counter != null)` in that case also create new instance and start your CountDownTimer don't cancel or stop!

Comment: If you set the counter to `null` and reinitialize it, it will be the same result as starting the timer over again.

Comment: I don't understand why..Its new object